# CSS Accordion Demo (4 Panes): Want To Double 8 Panes

Tags: css

I've made decent progress with a CSS accordion resource: http://www.rafikicai.com/8/#section-2

My problem is in going beyond the demo code, from 4 to 8 panes.  I'm clearly doing something
wrong, because the code is falling apart right around pane 4.

Can some CSS Wizard get me out of the forest and into the clearing again.  Thanks in advance,
for any and all helping hands.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem lies in the id's on your inputs.  Underneath each section (each div) of the accordion you have the following line of code:

`input id="ac-1" name="accordion-1" type="checkbox"`

(except some of the id's are a bit different)

You're using the same id's for some of your inputs, which is why clicking on one heading opens a different one.  Change the id's (and the 'for=...' on the line below) of each input so they are different and that should fix your problem.

Upon looking at your code again I saw the same problem with div's as mentioned by Ilya; make sure that you close each div that you open.  You open 2 div's for each section, but after sections 3, 4 and 5 you only close one of those div's.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have wrong nesting in the markup. The original accordion code probably had each group of the invisible checkbox, its label and corresponding section of content in one `div` wrapper. In the page you linked to, you have 4th and 8th sections in the same wrapper, as well as 5th and 7th sections (both nested inside 4th section for some reason). That's why the CSS selector

```
.accordion input:checked ~ .article.ac-small
```

in your code (line 96) is applied to both sections in the wrapper in which the first checkbox is checked, because so works the `~` combinator.